# How to split WriteStream while writing to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Problem:**

I have `fs.createWriteStream(filename)`, where filename is mp3 file being written via `res.pipe();`. The response from remote server is **never-ending stream of audio data**.

Time-to-time server sends `res.on('metadata')` which can be parsed and we understand that the song ended and new song begins. At that point I have to "split" the  "filename" and start writing another "filename2" which is eventually another song.

The problem, is that I can not close the stream for "filename1", and start another `fs.createWriteStream(filename2)`, as it's being used by "res.pipe()" and if it's closed pipe breaks -> node throws error that i cannot write into closed stream -> res breaks -> connection lost and i have to manually restart the app...

How it should be properly done?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to consider not using `res.pipe()` since you require finer control over the destination stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something in between the fs write streams and the response stream. You can create your own Writable for example, this is a crude example that you can still `res.pipe()` to and when you want to change files you call `writable.changeFile()`:

```
const { Writable } = require("stream");

class MyWritable extends Writable {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);

    this.doChangeFile = false;
    this.stream = null;
  }

  _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    if (!this.stream) {
      // No stream, start a new one
      const filename = "generate a new filename here";

      this.stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    }

    if (this.doChangeFile) {
      // Swapping files, end current stream and return
      this.stream.end(chunk, encoding, callback);
      this.stream = null;

      this.doChangeFile = false;
      return;
    }

    // Otherwise write chunks to current stream
    this.stream.write(chunk, encoding, callback);
  }

  changeFile() {
    this.doChangeFile = true;
  }
}

const writable = new MyWritable();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, will dive into it!